# Install particular version(2.15.2) of r-base on ubuntu

Tags: r, ubuntu, installation

I am newbie to both Ubuntu and R.

I am trying to install R 2.15.2 on ubuntu. Since the latest version of R is 3.0.X, I specified the version in /etc/apt/sources.list

deb http://cran.ma.imperial.ac.uk/bin/linux/ubuntu precise 2.15.2

Then I ran `sudo apt-get install r-base`.

It installs, but when I check version, it is 2.14.1, not 2.15.2

I tried to specify version in command line, such as:

`sudo apt-get install r-base_2.15.2_1precision1`

Always seeing:

> E: Unable to locate package r-base_2.15.2_1precision1.
>   E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'r-base_2.15.2_1precision1'

Any suggestion? Thanks.

If I run command:

```
sudo apt-get install r-base=2.15.2-1precise0
```

See the following message:

> The following packages have unmet dependencies:
>    r-base : Depends: r-recommended (= 2.15.2-1precise0) but 3.0.1-1precise0precise2 is to be installed
>             Recommends: r-base-html but it is not going to be installed

Comment: after adding the deb entry in sources.list did you run apt-get update ?

Comment: Hmm, after I do apt-get update, I am seeing 404 not found error:Error is W: Failed to fetch http://cran.ma.imperial.ac.uk/bin/linux/ubuntu/dists/precise/2.15.2/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Find the solution.

I need to install like:

```
sudo apt-get install r-base-core=2.15.3-1precise0precise1
sudo apt-get install r-recommended=2.15.3-1precise0precise1
sudo apt-get install r-doc-html=2.15.3-1precise0precise1
sudo apt-get install r-base=2.15.3-1precise0precise1
```

Comment: Hi, this does not work on my linuxMint17, any idea? THx

Answer (score 1):

Okay so the URL for where the packages are found has changed :^) on the cran.ma site:

Change the debian url to:

`deb http://cran.ma.imperial.ac.uk/bin/linux/ubuntu precise/`

do an `apt-get update` and try reinstalling

The complete instructions are on:

http://cran.ma.imperial.ac.uk/bin/linux/ubuntu/

Comment: This gives me the latest version, how to install some previous version, such as 2.15.2?