# Update R base - Ubuntu from 3.4.4 to 3.5.2 - Azure

Tags: r, azure, ubuntu, installation

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 on Azure Linux Virtual Machine

```
lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.5 LTS
Release:        16.04
Codename:       xenial
```

The current R version for Rstudio/Rserver is 3.4.4 and I would like to update it to the latest version (i.e. version 3.5.2)

```
R --version
R version 3.4.4 (2018-03-15) -- "Someone to Lean On"
Copyright (C) 2018 The R Foundation for Statistical Computing
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
```

From some reasons, the most common method doesn't work:

```
apt-get update
apt-get upgrade
```

So I did some research and find this [post](https://www.biostars.org/p/88651/) on biostars.org

One of the posts says the following codes might work

```
sudo su 
echo "deb https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu xenial-cran35/" >> /etc/apt/sources.list 
apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys E084DAB9 
apt-get update 
apt-get install r-base 
apt-get install r-base-dev
```

However, after `apt-get install r-base` I'm getting the following error message:

```
root@VMforR:/usr/local/bin# apt-get install r-base
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 r-base : Depends: r-recommended (= 3.5.2-1xenial) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I don't understand what "held broken packages" means, and more importantly, how to update the R base?

Answer (score 2):

What worked for me was to add the PPA of Michael Rutter:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:marutter/rrutter3.5
sudo apt-get update
```

Update R:

```
sudo apt install r-api-3.5
```

I'm with the 16.04 LTS ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

Have tried some other methods, the following seems to work:

```
sudo apt-get install r-base-core=3.5.2-1xenial
```

Ref:
1. [Install particular version(2.15.2) of r-base on ubuntu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16745470/install-particular-version2-15-2-of-r-base-on-ubuntu)
2. https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/linux/ubuntu/xenial-cran35/

But I'm not sure if this also work for others or not, as I can't reproduce it.

Answer (score 0):

After

```
apt-get update
```

do

```
apt-get dist-upgrade
```

first to "move your installation forward".  That includes upgrading already installed packages. It should just upgrade your R installation (unless you also switch / need to switch repositories).

The [r-sig-debian](https://stat.ethz.ch/mailman/listinfo/r-sig-debian) list is good and patient with basic 'how do it od X for R on Debian/Ubuntu'. Consider subscribing to lurk and/or ask questions.

Answer (score 0):

Mine said some of my packages were missing. So, I ran `sudo dpkg --configure -a` and then re-run the `R --update` and it worked to correct the missing package error.

Comment: Did you have a broken package? This doesn't seem like it answers the OP's question of what held broken packages and how to update with these broken packages.