# R: Can't install genius package in PopOS 21.04

Tags: r, linux, ubuntu, repository, rstudio

Just jumped from Windows to PopOS ver 21.04. I am in need of using R and specifically the genius package by JosiahParry. I have been searching all the way for a way to install the package with no outcome.
When given the plain `install.packages("genius")` command i get:

```
Error: object ‘session’ is not exported by 'namespace:rvest'
Ejecución interrumpida
ERROR: lazy loading failed for package ‘genius’
* removing ‘/home/emmuh/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.1/genius’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘genius’ had non-zero exit status
```

I haven't found a solution to this problem regarding package installation. I have also tried using the tar.gz file for direct installation and i get the following:

```
Error: object ‘session’ is not exported by 'namespace:rvest'
Ejecución interrumpida
ERROR: lazy loading failed for package ‘genius’
* removing ‘/home/emmuh/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.1/genius’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘/home/emmuh/Descargas/genius_2.2.3.tar.gz’ had non-zero exit status
```

I have tried changing repositories for the installation via the terminal but i get errors saying said repositories do not have a key or that they aren't safe so they will be unabled by omission.

When using RStudio Cloud i get no error whatsoever.

Comment: Sounds like you are running into an Ubuntu problem rather tna an R problem. There is an "Ask Ubuntu" forum. I suspect you need to add the proper credential for the marutter repo. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54068089/update-r-base-ubuntu-from-3-4-4-to-3-5-2-azure/55859342#55859342  (I was unable to reproduce you problem on an Ubuntu 18.04 installation, but I do have the marutter credential in my setup.

Comment: The link in the answer I found looks old. This page should have current instructions. https://launchpad.net/~marutter/+archive/ubuntu/rrutter

Answer (score 1):

I did a fresh install of Pop!OS and started downloading R and RStudio. With some reddit help and paying close atention at the errors, it turns out i was missing the rvest library, which needed openssl and libcurl installed via the terminal: `sudo apt install libcurl4-openssl-dev`  for libcurl and then the one for openssl. Didn't copy both installation codes, but R displayed it in the terminal (along a lot of other errors), which you just have to search for a bit. I was able to install genius with no further issues after that.